# Visual Studio 2015 without SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I just installed VS 2015 Community edition and notice that SQL Server was installed with the Windows 8.1 app tools. I'm a JavaScript developer and new to Visual Studio. The fact is that I don't want any SQL Servers on my development environment because I prefer to install my databases and servers on dedicated virtual machines.

Question is: is it safe to uninstall SQL Server from my computer?

I also have a version of Windows Server 2012, so I wish to run a vm with Windows Server 2012 + SQL Server and then connect from my dev env if needed.

Do you think it's possible and even a good choice?

Comment: Safest option: leave it there, but not running. Remember VS SQL tooling is itself partially dependent on some of the same components.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Richards. Do you mean SQL server not running as a background service at startup? If so, no matter...

Comment: remove it, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing it or leaving it on the system will make no difference. By the sounds of things it sounds like you should leave it though because you need managment studio, so I guess you could just stop the service..

Comment: It's weird, the powershell command 'Service-Stop MSSQLServer' returns objectNotFound ...

Comment: Use CMD ---  net stop MSSQL$instancename or if it's a default instance net stop MSSQLSERVER